# python multiprocessing how to kill listener worker at the end of processing

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, multiprocessing

I am using python `multiprocessing` where a number of workers are doing a job and queueing their output to a listener. The listener will then append their outputs into a `numpy` array as below:

```
def listener(q):
    global data

    while 1:
        m = q.get()
        if m == 'kill':
            print('FINISHED')
            # Save data to file
            break
        data = np.column_stack((data, m))
```

This is the main code

```
data = np.empty([0,6])

manager = mp.Manager()

q = manager.Queue()

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))

jobs = []

for i in range(100):
    job = pool.apply_async(process_data, (x1, x2, x3,))
    jobs.append(job)

for job in jobs:
    job.get()

q.put('kill')

pool.close()
```

`process data` is  a function that puts an array into the queue that the listener is then pulling from. The problem is that when running the code `print('FINISHED')` is never executed while `data` is being populated so I know that `listener` is working. I am also getting an output warning:

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if m == 'kill':
```

Trying to debug this I commented out the creation of worker jobs like the code below, and `FINISHED` actually prints and warning message disappears. Why is this happening?

```
data = np.empty([0,6])

manager = mp.Manager()

q = manager.Queue()

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))

jobs = []

#for i in range(100):
 #   job = pool.apply_async(process_data, (x1, x2, x3,))
  #  jobs.append(job)

#for job in jobs:
 #   job.get()

q.put('kill')

pool.close()
```

Comment: Try to call `pool.join()` after `pool.close()`

Comment: @AndrejKesely, tried it, still does not print 'FINISHED'

Comment: You can try to remove parts of your program (eg. removing numpy, global data etc.) - to get your skeleton program working. Then start adding features.

Comment: That doesnt really help @AndrejKesely, data is being populated correctly. 'kill' seems to not be populated since 'FINISHED' is not being printed

Comment: Did you try to call `task_done()` on queue in worker thread? https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.task_done

Comment: @AndrejKesely issues seems more clear now. I updated my question.Thanks